# Explain the semantics of concurrent languages with real analysis examples

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, automata

In computer science, concurrency is a property of systems in which several computations are executing simultaneously, and potentially interacting with each other.
I need to explain the concurrency theory from a mathematical point of view. Can someone give some concurrency examples in real analysis, or in topology.

Comment: If it isn't hard to describe, you may wish to include an explanation/definition of what it means to be a concurrent language.  It may be the case that someone less familiar with that particular area will nonetheless be able to answer your question if they knew what a concurrent language was.  Also, if the idea comes from something like automata theory or theory of computation you may want to add another tag (or 2) that will make your question easier to find for people who would know more about it.

Comment: Do you want to understand concurrency theory or do you want applications and related work that stems from analysis and topology? If you want to understand "the semantics of concurrency theory", analysis and topology are probably not good places to start.

Comment: @mrp I understand it in a computer science point of view. I need some simple examples related with analysis and topology

Answer (score 0):

Directed algebraic topology is a field of algebraic topology with applications towards in particular semaphores and deadlock detection. See e.g. [Raussen](http://people.math.aau.dk/~raussen/TALKS/diss.pdf).